# Porting Android 5.1.1 to RaspbrryPi2

Tags: android, raspberry-pi2, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I've been working on porting Android 5.1.1 to RaspberryPi2。
I compiled Android with the [device configuration](https://github.com/anholt/device_raspberrypi_rpi2)! and it succeed.

As for the kernel, I'm using the version 4.0 and compile with the configuration which is combined with bcm2709_defconfig, android-base.cfg and android-recommended.cfg.

But When I tried to boot it, LogCat show:

```
--------- beginning of main
I/installd(    0): installd firing up
I/Netd    (    0): Netd 1.0 starting
E/Netd    (    0): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    (    0): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    (    0): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    (    0): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
I/        (    0): debuggerd: Feb  1 2016 18:35:07
--------- beginning of system
I/Vold    (   84): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
I/lowmemorykiller(   82): Using in-kernel low memory killer interface
I/keystore(   94): SELinux: Keystore SELinux is disabled.
I/SurfaceFlinger(   85): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger(   85): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
F/libEGL  (   85): couldn't find an OpenGL ES implementation
--------- beginning of crash
F/libc    (   85): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 85 (surfaceflinger)
I/DEBUG   (   89): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   89): Build fingerprint: 'unknown'
I/DEBUG   (   89): Revision: '10489921'
I/DEBUG   (   89): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   (   89): pid: 85, tid: 85, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
I/DEBUG   (   89): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   (   89): Abort message: 'couldn't find an OpenGL ES implementation'
I/DEBUG   (   89):     r0 00000000  r1 00000055  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   89):     r4 b6f3ce38  r5 00000006  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   (   89):     r8 b6082000  r9 00000000  sl 00000000  fp be942b0c
I/DEBUG   (   89):     ip 00000055  sp be942580  lr b6e99745  pc b6ebcbd8  cpsr 60000010
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #00 pc 00039bd8  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #01 pc 00016741  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #02 pc 0001735f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #03 pc 00013b39  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #04 pc 00012f18  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #05 pc 00007c51  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+88)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #06 pc 000431bd  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #07 pc 00010795  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #08 pc 00010f45  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglGetDisplay+24)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #09 pc 00017815  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::init()+60)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #10 pc 00000af1  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #11 pc 00012dc9  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+44)
I/DEBUG   (   89):     #12 pc 00000c08  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
I/DEBUG   (   89): 
I/DEBUG   (   89): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_04
I/Netd    (  179): Netd 1.0 starting
E/Netd    (  179): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    (  179): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    (  179): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    (  179): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
I/SurfaceFlinger(  180): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger(  180): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
```

It repeats incessant. I checked the existence of libEGL.so, libGLESv1_CM.so, libGLESv2.so in /lib/ and libGLES_android.so in /lib/egl/.

Why these errors occur and how to fix it?

Comment: This is a question for the `android-porting` mailing list; the four libraries you mentioned are prebuilt libraries supported to you by the Khronos group, much like the Google Play app APK is supported by Google. It's not going to be easy because 1) you do not have source and 2) you're not going to build them...

Comment: @Shark Thanks. As I know, libGLESv1_CM.so and libGLESv2.so is the API of OpenGL; libGLESv1_CM_xxx.so and libGLESv2_xxx.so is the implementation of OpenGL with hardware accelaration.
lib/egl/libGLES_android.so is software implementation.
Am I right? Can I only use OpenGL software implementation?(I set the lib/egl/egl.cfg to 0 0 android, but it seems not working.)

Comment: If you're a platform vendor - yes; otherwise, the platform vendor will have to provide you with those libs so you can use them. It's not just something you can hack at home, really. A few entities will have to support you on the problem, and they will probably be the `hardware vendor`, the `product developer` and of course, the `Khronos group` or `their sub-division tasked with supporting your target platform/architecture`. FYI - Getting the said libraries off of HTC and using them on a Samsung device leads nowhere; you'll also need to ask khronos about Samsung drivers, for example...

Comment: But the libs could probably be found somewhere on the net, as much as more support on a more niche-friendly forum, such as an embedded-development mailing list or a forum dedicated to raspbery pi.

Comment: @Shark Obviously, I'm not the platform vendor. Can OpenGL of software implementation do the rendering work and deliver the image to FrameBuffer, only with FrameBuffer driver support in kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error most likely happened because `surfaceflinger` process jumped into **some** allocated memory, expecting to find OpenGL ES implementations / ordinals of methods it was planning to use; the methods weren't there and weren't found. An `abort signal` was raised, which is signified in the debug log (SIGABRT) and the process crashed normally.

```
I/DEBUG   (   89): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   (   89): Abort message: 'couldn't find an OpenGL ES implementation'
```

The OS, however, can't boot without surfaceflinger, so it tries again and again and gets stuck in that death loop. Dig out the fault addr, and try using `addr2line` to find the file that's causing the offence, and try fixing it...

That + the comment I gave you is the best I can do, unfortunatelly.